# What's the proper way to list authorship of appendix to a publication on a CV?

Tags: publications, cv

I'm collaborating with some others on an appendix to a historical paper for submission to a high profile journal. In the field the convention for authorship [appears similar to mathematics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102926) (see also [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66162/appendices-to-papers-authored-by-others)) in which authorship can be split between the main paper and appendices. Since the basic rule of thumb is that the CV should include all intellectual products what would be the proper way to include the appendix? Would it be appropriate to just include it as a publication, e.g.

**Author, A.**, Author, B., Author, C., “Appendix: Neat Computer Simulation Justifying Historical Argument.” Appendix to Author, C., "Historical Argument." *High Profile Journal*, vol. XX, no. XX, pp. XX-XX, XXXX.

Comment: How would such a work usually be cited?

Comment: @user2768 MLA calls for it to be cited as a separate work.

Comment: Cite it in your CV in the style suggested by MLA